# How to resolve Transaction check error while installing xrdp?

Tags: centos, yum, xrdp

I am using CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (core). I install XFCE gnome and trying to install xrdp so that i can connect via windows machine.

```
yum -y install xrdp xorg-x11-xinit
```

But i am getting below error.

> **Transaction check error:   file /usr/bin/intel-gen4asm from install of xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel-2.99.917-28.20180530.el7.x86_64 conflicts
>   with file from package intel-gpu-tools-2.99.917-22.20151206.el7.x86_64
>   file /usr/bin/intel-gen4disasm from install of
>   xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel-2.99.917-28.20180530.el7.x86_64 conflicts
>   with file from package intel-gpu-tools-2.99.917-22.20151206.el7.x86_64
>   **

I also tried

```
 yum update --skip-broken
```

but still getting the error. How to solve it?

Below are the commands executed and the output is given.
    yum repolist enabled

> Loaded plugins: aliases, auto-update-debuginfo, changelog,
>   fastestmirror, filter-data, fs-snapshot, kabi, keys, langpacks,
>   list-data,
>                 : local, merge-conf, ovl, post-transaction-actions, priorities, product-id, protectbase, ps, refresh-packagekit, remove-
>                 : with-leaves, rpm-warm-cache, search-disabled-repos, show-leaves, subscription-manager, tmprepo, tsflags, upgrade-helper,
>                 : verify, versionlock This system is not registered with Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
>   Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI Loading mirror speeds from
>   cached hostfile  * base: centos.mirror.ndchost.com  * extras:
>   centos.mirror.ndchost.com  * updates: centos.mirror.ndchost.com 0
>   packages excluded due to repository protections repo id
>   repo name
>   status
>   _local                                       Automatic local repo. (manged by the "local" yum plugin).                                800
>   base/7/x86_64                                CentOS-7 - Base
>   10,019 extras/7/x86_64                              CentOS-7 - Extras 
>   385 updates/7/x86_64                             CentOS-7 - Updates
>   1,493 repolist: 12,697

```
yum info xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel
```

> Loaded plugins: aliases, auto-update-debuginfo, changelog,
>   fastestmirror, filter-data, fs-snapshot, kabi, keys, langpacks,
>   list-data,
>                 : local, merge-conf, ovl, post-transaction-actions, priorities, product-id, protectbase, ps, refresh-packagekit, remove-
>                 : with-leaves, rpm-warm-cache, search-disabled-repos, show-leaves, subscription-manager, tmprepo, tsflags, upgrade-helper,
>                 : verify, versionlock This system is not registered with Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
>   Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI Loading mirror speeds from
>   cached hostfile  * base: centos.mirror.ndchost.com  * extras:
>   centos.mirror.ndchost.com  * updates: centos.mirror.ndchost.com 0
>   packages excluded due to repository protections Installed Packages
>   Name        : xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel Arch        : x86_64 Version
>   : 2.99.917 Release     : 22.20151206.el7 Size        : 202 k Repo
>   : installed From repo   : anaconda Summary     : Xorg X11 Intel video
>   driver development package URL         : http://www.x.org License
>   : MIT Description : X.Org X11 Intel video driver development package.
>
> Available Packages Name        : xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel Arch
>   : i686 Version     : 2.99.917 Release     : 28.20180530.el7 Size
>   : 81 k Repo        : base/7/x86_64 Summary     : Xorg X11 Intel video
>   driver development package URL         : http://www.x.org License
>   : MIT Description : X.Org X11 Intel video driver development package.
>
> Name        : xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel Arch        : x86_64 Version
>   : 2.99.917 Release     : 28.20180530.el7 Size        : 87 k Repo
>   : _local Summary     : Xorg X11 Intel video driver development package
>   URL         : http://www.x.org License     : MIT Description : X.Org
>   X11 Intel video driver development package.

```
yum info intel-gpu-tools
```

> Loaded plugins: aliases, auto-update-debuginfo, changelog,
>   fastestmirror, filter-data, fs-snapshot, kabi, keys, langpacks,
>   list-data,
>                 : local, merge-conf, ovl, post-transaction-actions, priorities, product-id, protectbase, ps, refresh-packagekit, remove-
>                 : with-leaves, rpm-warm-cache, search-disabled-repos, show-leaves, subscription-manager, tmprepo, tsflags, upgrade-helper,
>                 : verify, versionlock This system is not registered with Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
>   Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI Loading mirror speeds from
>   cached hostfile  * base: centos.mirror.ndchost.com  * extras:
>   centos.mirror.ndchost.com  * updates: centos.mirror.ndchost.com 0
>   packages excluded due to repository protections Installed Packages
>   Name        : intel-gpu-tools Arch        : x86_64 Version     :
>   2.99.917 Release     : 22.20151206.el7 Size        : 4.4 M Repo        : installed From repo   : anaconda Summary     : Debugging tools for
>   Intel graphics chips URL         : http://www.x.org License     : MIT
>   Description : Debugging tools for Intel graphics chips
>
> Available Packages Name        : intel-gpu-tools Arch        : x86_64
>   Version     : 2.99.917 Release     : 28.20180530.el7 Size        : 598
>   k Repo        : base/7/x86_64 Summary     : Debugging tools for Intel
>   graphics chips URL         : http://www.x.org License     : MIT
>   Description : Debugging tools for Intel graphics chips

Comment: Could you edit your question with how you installed `xrdp`? Ideally the commands and outputs of the installation of `xrdp` and `intel-gpu-tools` if you did it yourself would be great.

Comment: @Paradox i have updated the commands

Comment: I was hoping for the output of the installation process, actually. Could you try again to install and put the output in the question? Could you put the output of `yum repolist enabled`, `yum info intel-gpu-tools` and `yum info xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel`, please?